# Docs for sympy symbol naming conventions for special rendering?

Tags: python, sympy

Is there any documentation that lists the predefined symbol names (or spelling conventions) that sympy renders as specialized math symbols?  For instance, I found the ones shown below by trial and error.

[image: screen shot]

I've tried Google searches and searches within the sympy docs and source code without finding anything other than a listing of greek letter names.

I'm using sympy 0.7.6 (in ipython notebook 2.3).

Comment: I believe your are seeing LaTeX rendering of the symbol...so whatever LaTeX understands is what you will see, e.g. the name `x_1` will create an x with a subscript 1.

Comment: @smichr Thanks, it looks like the general rule is to omit the LaTex '\' when applying accents to symbols, e.g. 'vdot' instead of 'v\dot', and to keep the the '\' for non-alphanumerics.  Hopefully someone very familiar with sympy will post an answer that clarifies the rules exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This code file](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/latex.py) contains the items that are identified as LaTeX entities.

Comment: Accepted and thanks! Note that it's necessary to follow an outdated link to mathjax.org in a comment in the source code to see the full list of supported LaTeX symbols.   The currently equivalent link is http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=latex#supported-latex-commands

Comment: This link is now broken